# Sometimes nvidia drivers don't load - unknown display - low resolution

Tags: display, nvidia

Running into a weird issue. I recently installled eos 6 on my workstation. Installed latest nvidia drivers (from app center) just fine.

Now sometimes when I boot into eos the nvidia drivers don't load and the display goes into low resolution. The display setting also fails to recognize the display when this happens with unknown display error.

For now I'm able to solve this problem by rebooting my system (sometimes need to reboot a few times) to resolve this. However this is quite annoying. Any help appreciated.

System details:

GPU - nvidia rtx 2080S
Display - asus predator with gsync (1440p, 144hz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got fixed with this [PR](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/pull/1581). Just had to reinstall nvidia drivers from appcenter. Works perfectly on each boot now :)